# How do you prevent read access to firebase without authentication from overload requests

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

An example is say i have a child with lots of data in it and a user wants to attack my firebase to slow it down and increase my upload limit and sets to read this child over and over again not from my app but from their own creation.

How would i prevent this from happening when the child is a public child in that it does not require a user to be logged in to be read?

Is there a way to only allow a certain domain to access a firebase so that other users cannot just access my data from their domains?

Since all the data can be read via javascript and the javascript can be changed by the user can this also happen when someone changes the code on my site.  Also is this a potential problem with all databases RDBMS or non RDBMs and not just with Firebase?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out the "anonymous" login option provided by Firebase Simple Login: https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/simple-login-anonymous.html - this lets every visitor to your site authenticate with Firebase, and you can setup your security rules such that only anonymously authenticated visitors to your site can read data.

Most production apps will employ the security rules to restrict access to their data. Learn more about Firebase security rules here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/security-rules.html